# Join Two Queries with a function in one of them in ORACLE 11g

Tags: join, oracle11g

```
select * from ( select no,item,desc,user from table where no=1 ) x , 
select no,item,desc,max(item_date),user from table where no=1 group by no,item,desc) y where x.no=y.no
```

after run, it gives error:

```
ORA-00904: "Y"."NO" invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select x.*, y.* from 
( select no,item,desc,user from table where no=1 ) x , 
(select no,item,desc,max(item_date),user from table where no=1 group by no,item,desc ) y 
where x.no=y.no
```

Or:

```
select x.*, y.* from 

( select no,item,desc,user from table where no=1 ) x 

left join

(select no,item,desc,max(item_date),user from table where no=1 group by no,item,desc ) y 

on x.no=y.no
```

Using left/right/inner join depending on how you want your data to be joined, of course.